# How can I make this JSON in C#?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

How can I create this JSON string in C#?  If I don't want to create a ViewModel to serialize with Json.NET, is there any other way?

Please refer to the JSON string below:

```
{
    "1": { "1年期": "12", "13個月期": "13", "2年期": "24", "3年期": "36"},
    "2": { "1年期": "12", "13個月期": "13", "2年期": "24", "3年期": "36"},
    "3": { "1個月期": "1", "3個月期": "3", "6個月期": "6", "9個月期": "9", "1年期": "12", "13個月期": "13", "2年期": "24", "3年期": "36" }
};
```

Comment: just get rid of ';' to get a valid json object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>` to create the JSON.  First set up the dictionary with the data you want, then return it from your MVC controller using the `Json()` method like this:

```
public ActionResult GetMyJson()
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>()
    {
        {
            "1", new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "1年期", "12" },
                { "13個月期", "13" },
                { "2年期", "24" },
                { "3年期", "36" },
            }
        },
        {
            "2", new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "1年期", "12" },
                { "13個月期", "13" },
                { "2年期", "24" },
                { "3年期", "36" },
            }
        },
        {
            "3", new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "1個月期", "1" },
                { "3個月期", "3" },
                { "6個月期", "6" },
                { "9個月期", "9" },
                { "1年期", "12" },
                { "13個月期", "13" },
                { "2年期", "24" },
                { "3年期", "36" },
            }
        }
    };

    return Json(dict);
}
```

Alternatively, you can serialize the dictionary using Json.Net like this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, Formatting.Indented);
```

But if you do it this way, and you want to return the JSON from inside an MVC controller, you will need to use the `Content()` method instead:

```
return Content(json, "application/json");
```

Comment: Thanks you. Your way is perfect. I also use another way to reach what I need. Just for sharing...

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer to share...

```
JObject obj_1 = new JObject(
    new JProperty("12", "1年期"), 
    new JProperty("13", "13個月期"), 
    new JProperty("24", "2年期"), 
    new JProperty("36", "3年期")
);

JObject obj_2 = new JObject(
    new JProperty("12", "1年期"), 
    new JProperty("13", "13個月期"), 
    new JProperty("24", "2年期"), 
    new JProperty("36", "3年期")
);

JObject obj_3 = new JObject(
    new JProperty("1", "1個月期"), 
    new JProperty("3", "3個月期"), 
    new JProperty("6", "6個月期"), 
    new JProperty("9", "9個月期"), 
    new JProperty("12", "1年期"), 
    new JProperty("13", "13個月期"), 
    new JProperty("24", "2年期"), 
    new JProperty("36", "3年期")
);

JObject objectParent = new JObject();
objectParent.Add("1", obj_1);
objectParent.Add("2", obj_2);
objectParent.Add("3", obj_3);
```